# In Java, why do we need to subtract some numbers in boolean expression?

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean-expression

I'm having difficulty in figuring out why do we subtract numbers in the boolean expression part of the for loop.

Example 1: The goal is to count the numbers of the same 2 length long substrings of the each string.

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {

int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());

int count = 0;

for(int c = 0; c < len-1; c++)
{
 String sub1 = a.substring(c, c + 2);
 String sub2 = b.substring(c, c + 2);

 if(sub1.equals(sub2))
 count++;
}

return count;
}
```

Example 2: The goal is to return true if the array contains the {1, 2, 3}(in this order) indexes.

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums)
{

 for(int a = 0; a < nums.length -2; a++)
 { 
   if(nums[a] == 1 && nums[a+1] == 2 && nums[a+2] == 3)
   return true;
 }


return false;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the subtraction?

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to step through this code. Pay special attention to the value of each variable.

Comment: It's to avoid nasty [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`'s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indices start at 0. So if you have an array that has 10 values stored in it the first value will be stored in array[0] the second in array[1] all the way up to array[9].

```
int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length())
```

sets your len variable to the number of characters in whichever string is shorter (a or b).

So if a has 10 characters and b has 11 characters it will output a's length and set the value of your len variable to 10.

All strings are in essence arrays of characters. Remember arrays start at 0. So with there being 10 characters in this string, when you loop through each character you have to start at 0 and go to 9. len was set to the value of 10... well the index 10 does not exist in your string a. The last index in the string will be index 9.

Normally in a for loop in order to iterate through each element in an array you have to start with 0 (int c = 0;). Continuing the example, you would want to start at 0 and go to 9 in order to loop through each element in your string. That's why in a for loop you can put the -1...as in this example you don't want to try to access an element at index 10 cause it does not exist.

However, there are ways to get around using the -1....it is not mandatory. For instance let's look at your code:

```
for(int c = 0; c < len-1; c++)
```

c < len-1; is not correct **IF** you want to loop through and get **EVERY** character of your string. Continuing our example. We have 10 characters in our string. The way this for loop is set up we will only ever get 9 of those 10 characters (we will only loop 9 times). c < len-1,  len = 10; 10 - 1 = 9, c < 9 means that this loop can only iterate while c has a value between 0 and 8 (c less than 9)...that's only 9 iterations and we need 10 to get every character of the 10 character string. You can take out the -1 and this will loop through each character in your string. c < len; will iterate while c has a value between 0 and 9...once c hits a value of 10 it is no longer less than the value of len, it is equal to it. Therefore, it will stop looping.

Now, if you wanted to use the -1. You could have used c **<=** len-1; So your program would loop until the value of c is no longer less than or equal to the value of len-1 (9). Once c hits the value 10 it will stop looping.

Now in your code in your first for loop you are creating substrings from the index at value c to the index at value c + 2:

```
 String sub1 = a.substring(c, c + 2);
 String sub2 = b.substring(c, c + 2);
```

Because of this even with you using c < len-1; you will have an out of bounds error. When you get to the 9th character of your 10 character string you will run into a problem. You would be trying to create a substring from the 9th character stored at index 8 to the 11th character stored at index 10....oops that doesnt exist. You could take care of this with an if statement:

```
if((c+2) > 10)
{
   break;
}
```

This is just one way to handle this.

You could also use c < len - 2; this will loop up to the 7th index (where the 8th character is stored) and create a substring from that index to the 9th index (where the 10th character is stored).

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot to realize the whole picture, I really appreciate for all of your effort.

Comment: No problem at all! I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

It makes sure you don't try to access an indice that is outside the bounds of your array. This is more obvious in your second example:

```
for(int a = 0; a < nums.length -2; a++)
    if(nums[a] == 1 && nums[a+1] == 2 && nums[a+2] == 3)
```

You can see that it is trying to access an index `a + 2`. If in the last iteration `a` would be equal to `nums.length`, you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is why you only loop until `length - 2` because inside the loop you manually make up for it by adding `2` to it again. This results in `length - 2 + 2`, or, `length`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now things getting in the right place, I appreciate it!